# Fastest code to merge two matrices of different dimension in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have two matrices in Matlab `A` and `B` respectively of dimension `MxN` and `GxN`.

`M` can be greater or smaller than `G`.

`A` and `B` do not contain identical rows.

I want to construct a matrix `C` of dimension `Hx(N+2)` in the following way

```
C=[];
for i=1:size(A,1)
    %if A(i,1:end-1) coincides with a row in B(:,1:end-1) (it can coincide with only one row at most)
    %then C=[C;A(i,1:end) B(j,end)]; %where j is the index of the identical row in B

    %otherwise impose C=[C;A(i,1:end) 0]
end

for i=1:size(B,1)
    %if B(i,1:end-1) does not coincide with any row in A(:,1:end-1)
    %then impose C=[C; B(i,1:end-1) 0 B(i,end)];
end
```

For example:

```
A=[1 2 3 4 5 100; 6 7 8 9 10 101; 11 12 13 14 15 102];
B=[6 7 8 9 10 103; 15 16 17 18 19 104]
C=[1 2 3 4 5 100 0; 6 7 8 9 10 101 103; 11 12 13 14 16 102 0; 15 16 17 18 19 0 104]
```

As `M` and `G` can be very high, I am looking for the fastest way to perform this.

Comment: Just a remark: when you define `A` the first and second rows have 6 columns, while the third row has 5.

Comment: Sounds like you want an [outerjoin](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/outerjoin.html).

Comment: How can I put the zeros with outerjoin?

Comment: I use Octave, which doesn't have tables or any of the set join functions so I can't test it out, but it looks like it would put `NaN` values where you want zeros. Assuming you have no other `NaN`s in your data, they should be pretty easy to replace.

Comment: It does not seem to work with arrays. Maybe I could use `union` but I'm struggling in adapting it to my case

Comment: It looks like you can do the same thing with `union`. Let me play around for a bit. Does it matter if the rows of the output matrix are sorted?

Comment: No, it doesn't. thank you

Comment: `union` doesn't give me the information I need. rahnema1's solution should work though.

Comment: The answer provided by @Morc is more efficient than mine.so please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use `intersect` with a bit of preallocation to speed up the assignment (if M or G gets really large).

```
A=[1 2 3 4 5 100; 6 7 8 9 10 101; 11 12 13 14 15 102];
B=[6 7 8 9 10 103; 15 16 17 18 19 104];
C=[1 2 3 4 5 100 0; 6 7 8 9 10 101 103; 11 12 13 14 16 102 0; 15 16 17 18 19 0 104];

[M,N] = size(A);
G = size(B,1);

[tmp, idxA, idxB] = intersect(A(:,1:end-1),B(:,1:end-1),'rows')
idxBnotA = setdiff([1:G],idxB);

H = M + G - length(idxA);

C1 = zeros(H,N+1);

C1(1:M,1:N) = A;
C1(idxA,end) = B(idxB,end);
C1(M+1:end,1:end-2) = B(idxBnotA,1:end-1);
C1(M+1:end,end) = B(idxBnotA,end)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ismember` + indexing to do your task:

```
[idx1,idx2] = ismember(A(:,1:end-1), B(:,1:end-1), 'rows');
idx3 = ~ismember(B(:,1:end-1), A(:,1:end-1), 'rows');
C(idx1,:) = [A(idx1,:) B(idx2(idx1),end)];
C(~idx1,:) = [A(~idx1,:) zeros(sum(~idx1),1)];
C=[C;B(idx3,1:end-1) zeros(sum(idx3),1) B(idx3,end)];
```